# str.startsWith() not working on android phone

Tags: javascript, android

I am using javascript's function `.startsWith()` for check if string starts with `/assets`

Code is

```
 var str = '/assets/image';
 if(str.startsWith('/assets')){alert('done');}
```

This works fine on pc , But not working on android phone , is `.startsWith()` has any compatibility issues on different browser or devices,and if yes ,then please tell me if any alternative for `startsWith()`

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, it works good for me and give the same result.

```
var str = '/assets/image';
if(str.indexOf('/assets') === 0){alert('done');}
```

Answer (score 2):

`startsWith` is a pretty new addition to JavaScript and is not broadly supported on mobile browsers.

As basic alternative you can use

```
str.indexOf(strToFind) === 0
```

Or a polyfill presented on [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith)

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN, `startsWith()` is not supported at android. You can alternatively use `RegExp.prototype.test()`

```
var str = '/assets/image';
if(/^\/assets/.test(str)){alert('done');}
```

Comment: @beginner Yes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/startsWith#Browser_compatibility , https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test#Browser_compatibility